# Changing unique values in column to one of two specific values

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

#### Summary

I am trying to organize a data frame before I change the format of it. In my data.frame, there values under grouped under 2 factors (`factor1` or `factor2`). The levels in `factor2` are grouped in pairs (for example, 13 & 17) under `factor 1`.  Within each pair of `factor2`, I'd like to rename one of the numbers as `A` and the other `B`. The renaming order is arbitrary and either values can be `A` or `B`. Drawing from the previous example, 13 or 17 could be either A or B, as long as only number is given A and the other B. Note that some levels in `factor1` do not have a pair of data and may have only 1.

After which, I want to reshape the data frame into another format as shown below (see #3)

#### Here is a sample data.frame

```
sampledata <- data.frame(factor0 = c("A", "A", "H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "H", "A", "A",
                                     "H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "H", "A", "A", "H", "H"), 
                         factor1 = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "5", 
                                     "6", "6", "7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9", "10", "10"),
                         factor2 = c("13", "17", "14", "18", "5", "15", "19", "16", "20", "17",
                                     "18", "19", "21", "24", "27", "28", "30", "30", "17", "18"), 
                         value1 = c(1, 5, 6, 2, 6, 8, 10, 21, 30, 5, 3, 5, 4, 50, 4, 7, 15, 48, 20, 21,
                         value1.se = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.6, 0.8, 0.10, 0.21, 0.30, 0.5, 
                                                  0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 1.50, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 0.48, 2.1, 21)))
```

#### 1. At first, data table will look like:

```
> sampledata
#      factor0   factor1   factor2   value1   value1.se
# 1    A         1         13        1        0.5
# 2    A         1         17        5        0.5
# 3    H         1         14        6        0.6
# 4    H         1         18        2        0.2
# 5    A         2         5         6        0.6
# 6    A         2         15        8        0.8
# 7    H         2         19        10       0.10
# 8    H         2         16        21       0.21
```

#### 2. Afterwhich, the table will look like:

```
> sampledata
#      factor0    factor1   factor2   value1   value1.se
# 1    A          1         A         1        0.5
# 2    A          1         B         5        0.5
# 3    H          1         A         6        0.6
# 4    H          1         B         2        0.2
# 5    A          2         A         6        0.6
# 6    A          2         B         8        0.8
# 7    H          2         A        10       0.10
# 8    H          2         B        21       0.21
```

#### 3. Finally, the data table should look like:

```
> sampledata
#      factor0   factor1   value_A   value_B   se_A   se_B
# 1    A         1         1         5         0.5    0.5
# 2    H         1         6         2         0.6    0.2
# 3    A         2         6         8         0.6    0.8
# 4    H         2         10        21        0.10   0.21
```

I have another factor that i'd like to group by (`factor0`), but I think I can manage that on my own. The main reason why I want to organize the data in this fashion is so I can plot `value_A` and `valueB` against each other, with `factor0` being coloured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change `factor2` to values`A` or `B` using the length of the grouped data then reshape it using `pivot_wider()` (requires`tidyr` v1.0.0).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sampledata %>%
  group_by(factor0, factor1) %>%
  mutate(factor2 = c("A", "B")[sequence(n())]) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = factor2, values_from = c(value1, value1.se))

# A tibble: 10 x 6
# Groups:   factor0, factor1 [20]
   factor0 factor1 value1_A value1_B value1.se_A value1.se_B
   <fct>   <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 A       1              1        5         0.5        0.5 
 2 H       2              6        2         0.6        0.2 
 3 A       3              6        8         0.6        0.8 
 4 H       4             10       21         0.1        0.21
 5 A       5             30        5         0.3        0.5 
 6 H       6              3        5         0.3        0.5 
 7 A       7              4       50         0.4        1.5 
 8 H       8              4        7         1.4        1.7 
 9 A       9             15       48         1.5        0.48
10 H       10            20       21         2.1       21
```

Comment: I am getting `Error in factor(sequence(n()), labels =c("A", "B")): invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 1`

Comment: @Cam.S Seems like not all group combinations in your actual data have two cases. Edited to account for this.

Comment: yes I should have noted that. The new line of code is more robust though!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, we can first change `factor2` values in each group and use `dcast` to cast data from long to wide format.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(sampledata)[, factor2 := factor(LETTERS[1:2]), .(factor0, factor1)]
dcast(sampledata, factor0 + factor1 ~ factor2, value.var = c("value1", "value1.se"))

#    factor0 factor1 value1_A value1_B value1.se_A value1.se_B
# 1:       A       1        1        5         0.5        0.50
# 2:       A       3        6        8         0.6        0.80
# 3:       A       5       30        5         0.3        0.50
# 4:       A       7        4       50         0.4        1.50
# 5:       A       9       15       48         1.5        0.48
# 6:       H      10       20       21         2.1       21.00
# 7:       H       2        6        2         0.6        0.20
# 8:       H       4       10       21         0.1        0.21
# 9:       H       6        3        5         0.3        0.50
#10:       H       8        4        7         1.4        1.70
```